# Python Plotly Sankey diagram not showing up

Tags: python, json, jupyter-notebook, plotly, sankey-diagram

I am working in a Jupyter Notebook Python 3 (ipykernel) and trying to create a Sankey plot using plotly via importing a json file with the data. When I run my code, I receive no error, however, there is no plot just an empty output.

I am working from the "More complex Sankey diagram with colored links" example shown here: https://plotly.com/python/sankey-diagram/#reference

- I checked the json to make sure that there is no circularity (i.e., that the same two nodes are not being used as the source and target in two separate entries: e.g., entry1: source=A, target=B; entry2: source=B, target=A).
- Another post I found mentioned that the target number has to be greater than the source number https://community.plotly.com/t/cannot-plot-sankey-diagram/9734, so I check this as well at that is not the issue.
- I found another post here https://community.plotly.com/t/sankey-diagram-appearing-as-blank/4959/7 that said something about adding prefixes to the labels, but I was not able to find out what this means.

Any thoughts? Thank you!

Here is the code:

```py
import plotly.graph_objs as go
import json

with open("sankeywhst.json", 'r') as j:
     data = json.loads(j.read())

fig = go.Figure(data=[go.Sankey(
    valueformat = ".0f",
    valuesuffix = "TWh",
    # Define nodes
    node = dict(
      pad = 15,
      thickness = 15,
      line = dict(color = "black", width = 0.5),
      label =  data['data'][0]['node']['label'],
      color =  data['data'][0]['node']['color']
    ),
    # Add links
    link = dict(
      source =  data['data'][0]['link']['source'],
      target =  data['data'][0]['link']['target'],
      value =  data['data'][0]['link']['value'],
      label =  data['data'][0]['link']['label'],
      color =  data['data'][0]['link']['color']
))])

fig.update_layout(title_text="Flow of WHST Files",
                  font_size=10)
fig.show()
```

Here is the json:

```json
{"data": [
        {
            "type": "sankey",
            "domain": {
                "x": [
                    0,
                    1
                ],
                "y": [
                    0,
                    1
                ]
            },
            "orientation": "h",
            "valueformat": ".0f",
            "valuesuffix": "TWh",
            "node": {
                "pad": 15,
                "thickness": 15,
                "line": {
                    "color": "black",
                    "width": 0.5
                },
                "label": [
                    "All potentially generated",
                    "Generated",
                    "Not generated",
                    "Ingested within 48 hours",
                    "Ingested after 48 hours",
                    "Processed within 48 hours",
                    "Processed after 48 hours (already late)",
                    "Visualized within 48 hours",
                    "Visualized after 48 hours (otherwise on time)",
                    "Visualized after 48 hours (already late)",
                    "Excluded Fitbit Sleep files",
                    "Not intended for visualization: Fitbit Steps files",
                    "Not intended for visualization: Fitbit Steps files (already late)",
                    "Not intended for visualization: Fitbit Steps files (never generated)",
                    "Never visualized (otherwise on time)",
                    "Never visualized (already late)",
                    "Never visualized (never generated)"
                ],
                "color": [
                    "rgba(120, 0, 189, 0.8)",
                    "rgba(61, 0, 255, 0.8)",
                    "rgba(217, 0, 0, 0.8)",
                    "rgba(45, 100, 216, 0.8)",
                    "rgba(255, 128, 54, 0.8)",
                    "rgba(0, 210, 143, 0.8)",
                    "rgba(210, 94, 0, 0.8)",
                    "rgba(18, 197, 0, 0.8)",
                    "rgba(255, 210, 0, 0.8)",
                    "rgba(210, 94, 0, 0.8)",
                    "rgba(195, 0, 197, 0.8)",
                    "rgba(158, 0, 197, 0.8)",
                    "rgba(210, 94, 0, 0.8)",
                    "rgba(217, 0, 0, 0.8)",
                    "rgba(255, 210, 0, 0.8)",
                    "rgba(210, 94, 0, 0.8)",
                    "rgba(217, 0, 0, 0.8)"
                    ]
            },
            "link": {
                "source": [
                    0,
                    0,
                    1,
                    1,
                    2,
                    2,
                    3,
                    4,
                    5,
                    5,
                    5,
                    5,
                    5,
                    6,
                    6,
                    6    
                ],
                "target": [
                    1,
                    2,
                    3,
                    4,
                    13,
                    16,
                    5,
                    6,
                    10,
                    7,
                    8,
                    11,
                    14,
                    9,
                    12,
                    15  
                ],
                "value": [
                    924,
                    156,
                    891,
                    33,
                    24,
                    132,
                    891,
                    33,
                    9,
                    279,
                    410,
                    193,
                    0,
                    24,
                    8,
                    1
                ],
                "color": [
                    "rgba(120, 0, 189, 0.2)",
                    "rgba(120, 0, 189, 0.2)",
                    "rgba(61, 0, 255, 0.2)",
                    "rgba(61, 0, 255, 0.2)",
                    "rgba(217, 0, 0, 0.2)",
                    "rgba(217, 0, 0, 0.2)",
                    "rgba(45, 100, 216, 0.2)",
                    "rgba(255, 128, 54, 0.2)",
                    "rgba(0, 210, 143, 0.2)",
                    "rgba(0, 210, 143, 0.2)",
                    "rgba(0, 210, 143, 0.2)",
                    "rgba(0, 210, 143, 0.2)",
                    "rgba(0, 210, 143, 0.2)",
                    "rgba(210, 94, 0, 0.2)",
                    "rgba(210, 94, 0, 0.2)",
                    "rgba(210, 94, 0, 0.2)"
                ],
                "label": [
                    "",
                    "",
                    "",
                    "",
                    "",
                    "",
                    "",
                    "",
                    "",
                    "",
                    "",
                    "",
                    "",
                    "",
                    "",
                    ""
                ]
            }
        }],
    "layout": {
        "title": {"text": "WHST Combined Data Flow"},
        "width": 1118,
        "height": 772,
        "font": {
            "size": 10
        },
        "updatemenus": [
            {
                "y": 1,
                "buttons": [
                    {
                        "label": "Light",
                        "method": "relayout",
                        "args": [ "paper_bgcolor", "white" ]
                    },
                    {
                        "label": "Dark",
                        "method": "relayout",
                        "args": [ "paper_bgcolor", "black"]
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "y": 0.9,
                "buttons": [
                    {
                        "label": "Thick",
                        "method": "restyle",
                        "args": [ "node.thickness", 15 ]
                    },
                    {
                        "label": "Thin",
                        "method": "restyle",
                        "args": [ "node.thickness", 8]
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "y": 0.8,
                "buttons": [
                    {
                        "label": "Small gap",
                        "method": "restyle",
                        "args": [ "node.pad", 15 ]
                    },
                    {
                        "label": "Large gap",
                        "method": "restyle",
                        "args": [ "node.pad", 20]
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "y": 0.7,
                "buttons": [
                    {
                        "label": "Snap",
                        "method": "restyle",
                        "args": [ "arrangement", "snap" ]
                    },
                    {
                        "label": "Perpendicular",
                        "method": "restyle",
                        "args": [ "arrangement", "perpendicular"]
                    },
                    {
                        "label": "Freeform",
                        "method": "restyle",
                        "args": [ "arrangement", "freeform"]
                    },
                    {
                        "label": "Fixed",
                        "method": "restyle",
                        "args": [ "arrangement", "fixed"]
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "y": 0.6,
                "buttons": [
                    {
                        "label": "Horizontal",
                        "method": "restyle",
                        "args": [ "orientation", "h" ]
                    },
                    {
                        "label": "Vertical",
                        "method": "restyle",
                        "args": [ "orientation", "v"]
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Comment: "When I run my code, I receive no error, however, there is no plot just an empty output." Often you'll see that if things are not connected quite right for Jupyter to display output of the type produced. But maybe you know display of a Sankey plot works? You mention the demo  under 'More complex Sankey diagram with colored links'. Does that result show up where you are working? (Maybe if it does, you can parenthetically point that you in the post. Or at least next time write the post to include details ruling out things we cannot test on your machine?)

Comment: You were missing a `{` in front of `"data"` at the start of the supplied json. Pleas in the future test what you actually provide in fresh run. Please read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) especially the sections  'Help others reproduce the problem' and 'Proofread before posting!'.

Comment: Once I fixed the typo in your json...Both your code and the example under 'More complex Sankey diagram with colored links' in [the documentation 'Sankey Diagram in Python - How to make Sankey Diagrams in Python with Plotly.'](https://plotly.com/python/sankey-diagram/#more-complex-sankey-diagram-with-colored-links) work in Jupyter with no modification. When I ran in fresh JupyterLab 4.1 where I just had installed Plotly with `%pip install plotly` I had to refresh my browser (Command + `R` in Chrome on a Mac) before it would display. Otherwise, it was just empty spaceholder where it should show.

Comment: Clicking 'Launch Binder'  [here](https://gist.github.com/jtpio/f3f7aed7c87bb15e07009bb29a601ed8) was the source of fresh JupyterLab 4.1 without needed to install anything. Plotly is not installed there so I installed it with `%pip install plotly` and then refreshed the browser like I described. Restarting the kernel is always a good idea, too. If you click [here](https://mybinder.org/v2/gh/fomightez/3Dscatter_plot-binder/master?filepath=index.ipynb) you'll get a session with the older Jupyter Notebook interface **with Plotly already installed** so you don't need to do anything to get ...

Comment: <continued> your code or the demo to work. You can go [here](https://gist.github.com/jtpio/83b0b625cb3b6e05d7f3d8714f98182e) to launch Jupyter Notebook 7.1 by pressing on 'launch binder' there. **Plotly is already installed there** and all works with your code or the demo, although it did seem slower to render in that session. In conclusion, I suspect you don't have Plotly installed correctly? Or more likely 'fully'. I'm assuming you didn't try the demo code before modifying it? The demo is always a better place to start than troubleshooting and it is easier to share as it is self-contained.

Answer (score 0):

Here are two sites that explain how to output plotly graphs in Jupyter Notebooks:
The first by using additional libraries
[Plotly documentation](https://plotly.com/python/ipython-notebook-tutorial/).

The second by changing or explicit calling the renderer
[Plotly renderers](https://plotly.com/python/renderers/).
Hopefully, one of these options works for you.

***EDIT***
I tested the code and the JSON. It all works after I change the last line into `fig.show(renderer="browser")`. What has worked for me in the past is taking the following steps when checking if a Plotly figure is successfully created. First, check if there is anything in `fig.data`. This should contain a tuple with at least one item and that is a Sankey diagram. If that is the case and knowing that the figure is created, the second step is finding a renderer that works in your setup by going through them one after an other. After a while you'll know which renderers work for you.